# Appending data to same collection after every pagination fetch

Tags: backbone.js

I am trying to populate instagram images using backbone,

I have basically 3 models as follows,

**User model store all the user info related to instagram**

```
App.Models.User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        id: '',
        access_token: '',
        userid: '',
        username: '',
        full_name: '',
        profile_picture: ''
    },
    urlRoot: "/api/user/",
    initurl: function() {
        return "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/"+this.get('userid')+"/media/recent/?access_token=" + this.get('access_token');
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.set('id', $('#domdump .id').val());
        this.fetch({
            success: function(model) {
                var photos = new App.Collections.Ig_photos([],{
                    url: model.initurl()
                });
            }
        });
    }

});
```

**A model to store the next url for pagination**

```
App.Models.Ig_next_url = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        next_url: ''
    },
    next_url:function(){
        return this.get('next_url');
    }
});
```

**A model for the photo**

```
App.Models.Ig_photo = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

**A collection for the multiple photo**

```
App.Collections.Ig_photos = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.Models.Ig_photo,
    initialize: function(model, options) {
        this.url = options.url;
        this.nextSet();
    },
    sync: sync_jsonp,
    parse: function( response ) {
        if(response.pagination && response.pagination.next_url && response.pagination.next_url != this.url){
            var next_url = new App.Models.Ig_next_url({ next_url: response.pagination.next_url });
            this.url = next_url.next_url();
        }
        return response.data;
    },
    nextSet: function(){
        this.fetch({
            success: function(photos){
                var ig_photos_views = new App.Views.Ig_photos_view({ collection: photos});
                console.log(photos);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Also i have some views that does the render with a load more button that calls the nextset of the collection.

What i was trying to achieve is the photos get appended to the collection upon nextset() and the collection get updated with pervious data + new data but right now its getting overwritten.

Also is it okay to instantiate new collection from the modelfetch ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't need to make a new view. You should instead listen to the "add" event being triggered on the collection and render new items accordingly.

```
nextSet: function(){
    this.fetch({add : true}); // The add option appends to the collection
}
```

This option is detailed in the [very good documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch).

Comment: Amazing your genius thanks. I was about to override the fetch method.

Comment: Glad I could help. The docs are actually very good for Backbone and they also offer fully annotated source code. Both are good places to check when you are trying to figure out what all you can do. Another good thing to note since you are playing with collections is that the  `Backbone.Collection` includes all of the awesome `Underscore.js` methods directly. This can save you a lot when trying to manipulate collection models.

Comment: I had to use the `remove` option for this to work for me, i.e. `this.fetch({remove: false})`. The options seem to be delegated to the [`collection.set`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-set) function.